# How to check index key block size in mysql

Tags: mysql

I used MySQL 8.0

```
CREATE TABLE `PK_KEY_BLOCK_SIZE` (
`COL`  VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL COMMENT 'new Column',
`COL2` VARCHAR(25) NULL     COMMENT 'new Column2', 
`COL3` VARCHAR(25) NULL     COMMENT 'new Column3' ) COMMENT 'new Table';

ALTER TABLE `PK_KEY_BLOCK_SIZE`
ADD CONSTRAINT `PK_PK_KEY_BLOCK_SIZE`
    PRIMARY KEY (
        `COL` -- new Column
    )
    KEY_BLOCK_SIZE = 8;
```

What query can I use to check the Key_block_Size value?

Comment: Per-index KEY_BLOCK_SIZE value is the size in bytes, so `8` is invalid value, it will be adjusted (to 1024 primarily) or ignored. If the engine is not MyISAM then this setting will be ignored anycase. For InnoDB you must use table-level KEY_BLOCK_SIZE with ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED (pay attention - the setting meaning differs from one for MyISAM index-level setting).

Answer (score 2):

`show create table pk_key_block_size` will show you the table definition.

Per [manual - create table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html) KEY_BLOCK_SIZE is for MyISAM tables which from 8.0 isn't the default storage engine.

Looking at the MySQL-8.0 server code KEY_BLOCK_SIZE has some impact on innodb compressed pages.

Comment: Yes - MyISAM actually not the default storage engine since version 5.5, circa 2010!